# How to get font size of currently selected text in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mshtml

Is there any way to get the font size of the currently selected text in the Microsoft WebBrowser control (MSHTML)?

I am aware of `IHTMLDocument2::queryCommandState("FontSize", ...)`, but this method only returns a value between 1 and 7, for the outdated font sizes "xx-small" to "xx-large". For font sizes like "10pt" or "14px", no useful value is returned.

Is there a more flexible way to determine the font size?

**EDIT:** In the meantime, I found a solution to my question (with some helpful hints from Microsoft support):

```
try
{
   mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange range = _dom.selection.createRange() as mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange;
   if (range != null)
   {
       mshtml.IHTMLElement2 elem = range.parentElement() as mshtml.IHTMLElement2;
       txtFontSize.Text = elem.currentStyle.fontSize.ToString();

   }
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you found out how to get it, here is a way to set it up.

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = [Obtain HtmlDocument];
doc.execCommand("FontSize", false, "12pt");
```

To get the value you can use

```
doc.queryCommandValue("FontSize");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = browser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

IHTMLSelectionObject sel = (IHTMLSelectionObject)htmlDocument.selection;
IHTMLTxtRange range = (IHTMLTxtRange)sel.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;

if (range != null)
{
   range.select();
   var x = range.queryCommandValue("bold");
   textBoxFindData.Text = (x.ToString());
}
```